# Speech Recognition and AudioPlaying working on simulator but not on iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

im trying to use speech recognition to transform it into text and display it. Speech Recognition and AudioPlaying working on simulator but not on iPhone? Why is that the case ?

I get this error in console when trying recognition on iphone:

> Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=203 "Corrupt" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Corrupt, NSUnderlyingError=0x28063f240 {Error Domain=SiriSpeechErrorDomain Code=102 "(null)"}}

That´s my code:

```
func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
    self.animateSpinner(forStatus: false)
    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: recorder.url)
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch let error {
        debugPrint(error)
    }

    SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization({ (authStatus) in
        if authStatus == .authorized {
            let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: self.language))
            let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: recorder.url)
            recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    debugPrint(err)
                    return
                }
                self.textView.text = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString
            })
        }
    })
}
```

and here is the setup of the recorder in viewDidLoad()

```
func setupRecorder() {
    let dirPaths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                            in: .userDomainMask)

    let soundFileURL = dirPaths[0].appendingPathComponent("sound.caf")
    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: soundFileURL, settings: [
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.min.rawValue,
            AVEncoderBitRateKey: 16,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0])
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    }
    catch let error {
        debugPrint(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Check with other iPhones, may be phone's siri facing some issue.

Comment: I tried but i am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Calling this in `viewDidLoad` fixed the issue:

```
var audioSession: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .spokenAudio, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch let error{
        print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error: ", error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { authStatus in
    if authStatus == SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
        if let path = Bundle.main().urlForResource("test", withExtension: "m4a") {
            let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
            let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: path)
             request.cancel()
            recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("There was an error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print (result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

cancel the request before you start recognizing. check the code here

Answer (score 0):

For me, add

```
inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
sleep(1)
```

before

```
inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 4096, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
            self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)}
```

solve the problem